# How to use databricks dbx with an Azure VPN?

Tags: azure-databricks, hive-metastore, databricks-dbx

I am using [dbx](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/) to [deploy](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/python/python_quickstart/?h=dbx+deploy#deploying-the-workflow) and [launch](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/python/python_quickstart/?h=dbx+deploy#launching-the-workflow) jobs on ephemeral clusters on Databricks.
I have initialized the [cicd-sample-project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/dbx#--create-a-dbx-templated-project-for-python-with-cicd-support) and connected to a fresh empty Databricks Free trial environment and everything works (this means, that I can successfully deploy the python package with this command
`python -m  dbx deploy cicd-sample-project-sample-etl --assets-only`
and execute it through the `python -m  dbx launch cicd-sample-project-sample-etl --from-assets --trace`

When I try to launch the same exact job on my company's Databricks environment the deploy command goes through. The only difference is that my company's Databricks environment connects to Azure through a VPN.

Therefore, I added some rules to my firewall
[firewall_rules_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR1Kc.png)
[firewall_rules_2_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QACdy.png)

but when I give the `dbx launch` command I get the following error
[error_node_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzY2c.png)
and in the log this message appears

> WARN MetastoreMonitor: Failed to connect to the metastore InternalMysqlMetastore(DbMetastoreConfig{host=consolidated-westeuropec2-prod-metastore-3.mysql.database.azure.com, port=3306, dbName=organization5367007285973203, user=[REDACTED]}). (timeSinceLastSuccess=0) org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToObtainConnectionException: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: metastore-monitor - Connection is not available, request timed out after 15090ms. at org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI.open(DBI.java:230)

I am not even trying to write on the metastore, I am just logging some data:

```
from cicd_sample_project.common import Task


class SampleETLTask(Task):
    def launch(self):
        self.logger.info("Launching sample ETL task")
        self.logger.info("Sample ETL task finished!")


def entrypoint():  # pragma: no cover
    task = SampleETLTask()
    task.launch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entrypoint()
```

Does someone encountered the same problem? Where you able to use Databricks-dbx with an Azure VPN?
Please let me know and thanks for your help.

PS: If needed I can provide the full log

Answer (score 1):

In your case the egress traffic isn't configured correctly - it's not the DBX problem, but general Databricks networking problem. Just make sure that outgoing traffic is allowed to the [ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject#network-security-group-rules-for-workspaces-created-after-january-13-2020) and [destinations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/udr#--metastore-artifact-blob-storage-log-blob-storage-and-event-hub-endpoint-ip-addresses) described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
Indeed a colleague find out that some routes were missing and adding them fixed the problem.
For everyone else that may encounter the same problem, please have a look at [Configure user-defined routes with Azure service tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/udr#--configure-user-defined-routes-with-azure-service-tags)